# Long, slow boot time for Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dmesg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, boot takes a long time. Attached is bootchart and dmesg log

http://postimg.org/image/6nepau6fh/

dmesg text went over the character limit so I'm pasting a few time leaps:

```
[ 0.347842] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[ 1.246343] Freeing initrd memory: 27216K (f4ac8000 - f655c000)

[   11.866672] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   22.475855] bio: create slab  at 1
[   22.727732] bio: create slab  at 1
[   23.771056] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   29.309548] Adding 1560572k swap on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1560572k FS

[   35.628292] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[   42.801867] intel_rng: FWH not detected

[   51.327763] init: failsafe main process (666) killed by TERM signal
[   57.023333] audit_printk_skb: 54 callbacks suppressed

[   58.543541] type=1400 audit(1411366692.308:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=985 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   64.814585] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Googling these has me mostly confused. Would appreciate any thoughts

Comment: While I'm not knowledgable in reading dmesg output, here's what i found useful to increase boot speed, specifically  refer to  "Reduce Boot Menu Delay" part : http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Have you upgraded your system from 12.04 or some older version, and maybe several upgrades before that?

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of minutes of boot time is a bit much than normal, but is still possible most than likely on some old machines. You didn't include your hardware configuration details, but the measured time is more than 115 sec, which makes me think that at least you have a hard drive disk in there not a solid state drive.

If you are looking for performance increase I would suggest upgrade/change your hard drive to SSD. It's not a tricky turn after all if you are not about purchasing a new computer.

Even having SSD drive in old machine will bring a performance increase because the device will not suffer with big time delays due to fragmentation.